# Can you embed a YouTube video showing only the video (with no title, etc)?

Tags: youtube

Can you embed a YouTube video showing only the video? Ie. without the initial load showing the information shown below, like the title:

[image]

[This statement from YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#release_notes_08_23_2018) suggests you can't, saying "the channel avatar and video title will always display before playback begins, when playback is paused, and when playback ends". But I thought I'd check if this has changed since, plus leave my finding here for anyone searching for the same question.

Comment: Does it need to be YouTube? If it is for your own videos, Vimeo is more flexible about what options appear over the video.

Comment: It is! Though I think you have to have the play button and scrubber. My question is about YouTube though.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to simply show the initial image without the playing the video and don't mind the avatar showing once the user clicks to play the video, check out [Labnol Lazyload video](https://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/).

It will only display the initial image, without showing the YouTube iframe until the user clicks on the play button.  It's also a great way defer downloading the YouTube video until the user clicks play.

Comment: I believe that modifying the embed Youtube player is against the Youtube terms of service.   Using that could trigger Youtube to block videos from playing on your site.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller.  Interesting.  I think you're already familiar with the methodology right?  I guess one could argue that you haven't embedded their player it until after the user clicks on the play button.

Comment: The most problematic part would be using the front image before the player loads.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller, of course you can always host your own initial image.  I tried this once to try and improve performance.

Comment: Thanks - I'm looking for autoplay, but this'll be a helpful answer for others, upvoted.